# WSGI with python3 not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib, wsgi

I'm trying to run python on the web to do some CSS/JSS extraction from websites. I'm using mod_wsgi as my interface for python. I've been following [this](http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_request_parsing_get) website to get an idea on getting started. 
The below is their sample code.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# Our tutorial's WSGI server
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def application(environ, start_response):

   # Sorting and stringifying the environment key, value pairs
   response_body = ['%s: %s' % (key, value)
                    for key, value in sorted(environ.items())]
   response_body = '\n'.join(response_body)

   status = '200 OK'
   response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
                  ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body)))]
   start_response(status, response_headers)

   return [response_body]

# Instantiate the WSGI server.
# It will receive the request, pass it to the application
# and send the application's response to the client
httpd = make_server(
   'localhost', # The host name.
   8051, # A port number where to wait for the request.
   application # Our application object name, in this case a function.
   )

# Wait for a single request, serve it and quit.
httpd.handle_request()
```

While this runs fine with python 2.7, I can't get it to run on Python 3. For my CSS/JSS extraction, I have modified the above code and put in my own functionalities which use BeautifulSoup and urllib3. While for using those modules I need python 3, for the WSGI code I need python 2.7. Hence, I can't merge the two. When trying to run BS and urllib in python3, I get an error. But when I try to run the WSGI code with python3, I'm just unable to load the webpage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Any workarounds, or suggestions as well.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: When I run it using python filename.py I get an error on importing urllib, i.e,  ImportError: No module named request (on the import urllib.request line). When I run it using python3 filename.py, I don't get an error at first but when I try to open localhost:8051, I get "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator" error on a blank page